# how to show image with json url in android list view

Tags: java, android, json

I write program to get data(text) from json and show it in list view , i write  the code and its working but now i get url of image with json but i dont know how to show the image in list view with image view,
please help me

here is my code

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pd;
JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> P;
JSONArray s=null;
private final String url="http://192.168.1.4:81/upload/travel.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    P = new ArrayList<>();
    new travel().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String id_code=((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.id_code)).getText().toString();
    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ADD.class);
    in.putExtra("id",id_code);
    startActivity(in);

}

class travel extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("login");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> parms=new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject json=jParser.makeHTTPRequest(url,"GET");

        try {
            int t=json.getInt("t");
            if(t==1){
                s=json.getJSONArray("travel");
                for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c=s.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id=c.getString("id");
                    String companyname=c.getString("companyname");
                    String cod=c.getString("cod");
                    String bign=c.getString("bign");
                    String stop=c.getString("stop");
                    String date=c.getString("date");
                    String time=c.getString("time");
                    String price=c.getString("price");
                    String url_image=c.getString("url_image");

                    HashMap<String,String>map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    map.put("id",id);
                    map.put("companyname",companyname);
                    map.put("cod",cod);
                    map.put("bign",bign);
                    map.put("stop",stop);
                    map.put("date",date);
                    map.put("time",time);
                    map.put("price",price);
                    map.put("url_image",url_image);

                    P.add(map);

                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, P, R.layout.item_list,
                        new String[]{"url_image","companyname", "cod", "bign", "stop", "date", "time", "price"},
                        new int[]{R.id.id_code,R.id.companyname, R.id.cod, R.id.bign, R.id.stop, R.id.date, R.id.time1, R.id.price});


                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Comment: you should try picasso or glide library

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you use best library for image loading ASYNC 
[PICASSO LIBRARY LINK](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Now you should write code

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

to show image from url into an ImageView use this class:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

In order to use it just use this command in your code:

```
new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(imageLinkURL);
```

Comment: i should use this code"new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(imageLinkURL);
" in oncreate function thats right?

Comment: no, after you get the URL of the image use it, insert the imageView of the place you want the image to be shown and the URL you recieved in the execute. it will asynchronous download the image from the url and when its done it will show it on the imageview

Comment: I use my imageview but its show me the error,my code=>new DownloadImageTask(R.id.imageView).execute(url);

Comment: I think you've got it wrong.. try ImageView myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView); and then pass myImageView inside as new DownloadImageTask(myImageView).execute(url);

Comment: i insert it with no error but when i run program ,its close immediately

Comment: i insert "new DownloadImageTask(image1).execute(url);" after runOnUiThread in protected void onPostExecute and program closed after i run it.

Comment: I can't really understand whats going on.. what is image1? and why did you put it there?

basically you should call that line once you have the url link.. try at first just using it on its own.. create new activity with imageView, find it by ImageView img = findViewByID(R.id.imageView); and then call the new DownloadImageTask(img).execute("image.com");

Comment: i try your code in new activity and its working but still i cant use this code in my json activity(MainActivity)

Comment: ok so back to my question, what exactly is image1? can you update your code with it?

Comment: in this code =>"ImageView img = findViewByID(R.id.imageView);" you use img but i use image1,and i update it